# Overriding default names of Laravel timestamps not having any effect

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to override the default names of the Laravel timestamps on a particular table, but it seems to be having no effect at all.

I have updated my model with the following:

```
/**
 * The name of the "created_at" column.
 *
 * @var string
 */
const CREATED_AT = 'CreatedAt';



/**
 * The name of the "updated_at" column.
 *
 * @var string
 */
const UPDATED_AT = 'UpdatedAt';
```

Updated the migration:

```
    ...
    $table->integer( 'UpdatedBy' )->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I run the migration and check the results in my database, and find that the fields have not changed:

```
...
| UpdatedBy             | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL                                    |                |
| created_at            | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL                                    |                |
| updated_at            | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL                                    |                |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+-----------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Have I missed something maybe?

Comment: 1. Does your migration also include the `CreatedAt` field you specified? 2. You specified `UpdatedBy` as `integer`, but not that your timestamp fields should be integers.  If you want to change from `timestamp` to `integer`, you need to add `protected $dateFormat = 'U';`, as [described in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions).

Comment: My migration just included the `timestamps();` function and I was hoping to override the field names by declaring them in the model from what I have read on a number of forums.  The `UpdatedBy` is an integer that links to my user table to define the Id of the user who updated the record. I do not wish to change date formats, only field names.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry, I misunderstood, I thought you were showing us `UpdatedBy` bcs it was a timestamp col. You are rolling the migration back and re-running, right, in other words creating the table from scratch, not just updating an already existing table?

Comment: All good. Yes, I am creating the migration fresh with `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`.  I even ran `php artisan migrate:reset` just to ensure I was starting with a totally blank canvas.

Answer (score 1):

If you check `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint` you must be see that.

```
public function timestamps()
{
    $this->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();

    $this->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
}
```

If you wont to change your `created_at`, and `updated_at` columns then you can use

```
...
    $table->integer( 'UpdatedBy' )->nullable();
    $table->timestamp(CorrespondModel::CREATED_AT)->nullable();
    $table->timestamp(CorrespondModel::UPDATED_AT)->nullable();
});
```

or directly create new names

```
...
    $table->integer( 'UpdatedBy' )->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('CreatedAt')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('UpdatedAt')->nullable();
});
```

Comment: So I can't just override in the `model` like every post seems to advise?

Comment: But won't this mean I'll have to manually maintain the timestamps?

Comment: Well in that case, I might as well just exclude the timestamps with `public $timestamps = false;` and declare my own timestamps.

Comment: Not change only migrations table , and use freely `const CREATED_AT = 'CreatedAt';` timestamps constants
`